# What Is The Reason For The Lein Cyclic Dependency Error When I build uberwar?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

Building ring server-headless works -- `lein ring server-headless` -- but when I try to build the war or uberwar I get the following error, and cannot figure out why this is happening.

```
No namespaces to :aot compile listed in project.clj.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, compiling:(ring/util/servlet.clj:62)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6416)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
...

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2013)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr.maybeClass(Compiler.java:938)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr.access$400(Compiler.java:710)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1(Compiler.java:6342)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6395)
... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Cyclic load dependency: [ /servlet ]->/ring/util/servlet->[ /servlet ]
at clojure.core$check_cyclic_dependency.invoke(core.clj:5288)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5383)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
at servlet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 76 more
```

My project.clj file is:

```
(defproject myproj "0.1"
:description "the sample"
:dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
    [compojure "1.0.4"]
    [hiccup "1.0.0"]
    [clj-json "0.5.0"]
    [ring/ring "1.1.0"]
    [clj-http "0.1.1"]
]   
:plugins [
    [lein-ring "0.7.0"]
]   
:ring {:handler routes/start})
```

If I remove the `:ring {:handler routes/start}` then I get a NPE somewhere else.

I don't know if I'm missing something in my project.clj, or if the particular version of lein is broken for this use case. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: can someone tell me why this is not a real question? At this point I can't tell if lein is broken, or if my project is not set up properly. To the best of my knowledge I've set up the project correctly but I can't get a common use case working. Please enlighten me as to why this is a bad question, or why it is not a "real" question.

Comment: I've solved the issue on my own. Neither posted answer is correct.

Comment: The basic issue is that `routes/start` was declared a `def` not a `defn` (not provided in question, because I didn't realize it was relevent until after I solved the problem). A very small detail that's easy to overlook, but in retrospect the behavior I was seeing makes perfect sense.

Comment: Glad you figured out. Perhaps post a detailed answer if this reopens?

Comment: @Kevin: I ran into this problem myself a while back. Can you post a detailed answer? I would find it helpful.

Comment: The question was closed as "not a real question" so I can't answer until it reopens.

Comment: @user1311390: I posted a detailed answer into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue, which was a bit of a mistake on my part. Posting the answer here in case anyone makes the same mistake.

I had something like the following in src/routes.clj:

```
(defroutes main-routes
    (GET "/some/path" [& params] (some-code params))
    (route/resources "/")
    (route/not-found "not found"))

(def start (run-jetty (handler/site main-routes) {:port 8080}))
```

This is all standard code to setup routes and provide a hook to start the jetty webapp from the command line via lein ring server-headless. Except that I declared start as a global instead of a function. That means when I run lein ring server-headless things still work, but when I run lein ring uberwar I end up with a weird configuration--a full jetty server will try to start up with it's servlet, AND uberwar has generated a servlet and is trying to package it into a jar.

When I was comparing my code against the compojure examples I kept missing this difference I guess because def and defn optically look so similar. But anyway I just made this change to get it working:

```
(defn start [] (run-jetty (handler/site main-routes) {:port 8080}))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, in my case the solution was as simple as doing a

> lein clean

before the

> lein ring uberwar

I think actual issue is that at some point, my handler was pointing to an incorrect/inexistent handler and that left a servlet.clj in the target/classes directory. Doing a clean will remove this file.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried that but I'll give it another go and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, the :aot param is missing from the project config. Check out [this link](http://asymmetrical-view.com/2010/06/08/building-standalone-jars-wtih-leiningen.html) for using :aot.

Comment: It's a webapp so it doesnt have a main. And I thought Lein generates the servlet automatically? That was certainly the case at one point...

Comment: I can add `:aot :all` and the stack trace goes away when I run `lein ring uberwar` (good) but it starts up the webapp as if I had run `server-headless` (bad).